# how to Login gmail using Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Hi all am trying to automate login the gmail account using python but am unable to do so , it just opens the gmail but nothing happens, what am i missing?

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/INCT-KaviChand/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

browser.get('http://gmail.com')

emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
emailElem.send_keys('kavi')
nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('next')
nextButton.click()
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id('kavisam')
passwordElem.send_keys('MyPassword')
signinButton = browser.find_element_by_id('signIn')
signinButton.click()



also tried below one 


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/INCT-KaviChand/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('http://gmail.com')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
emailElem.send_keys("abc@gmail.com")
password_elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'Passwd')))
password_elem.send_keys("xyz")
browser.find_element_by_name('signIn').click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find element in different way, code below is working for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/TestFiles/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://gmail.com')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]').send_keys('example', Keys.ENTER)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@type="password"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="password"]').send_keys('example', Keys.ENTER)
```